# Types issue (TypeScript nullable check Nuxt 3 & Vue 3)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, webstorm, nuxtjs3

I work with Nuxt & Vue on a new project and I have an issue with types (only with `.vue` files). My IDE is WebStorm (2022.2.2). See below:

The computed `product` is typed as `Product | undefined` (because I use the find function):

[image]

But, when I use it in my template, `product` type is `Product`, so TypeScript should report errors here, because type is possibility undefined.

[image]

I've already enabled Coding Assistance for Node.js

NOTE: with VSCode no issue:

[image]

My *tsconfig.json* :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Thank you and have a good day !

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57160/Prop-type-is-not-correct-in-templateVue; if you believe that your issue is different, please file a ticket to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB) providing a minimal code sample it can be repeated with